# Python - Sending "Incomplete" GET requests

Tags: python, sockets, http, request

So I was reading about these partial GET requests that would make a server timeout the connection after a while on this request. How would send a partial GET request?..

```
import socket, sys
host = sys.argv[1]

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+host+"\n\nUser-Agent:Mozilla 5.0\n" #How could I make this into a partial request?

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, 80))
s.sendto(request, (host, 80))
response = s.recv(1024)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use modules like `urllib`, `requests`, ..?

Comment: I was making it like that first, but I wanted to show the "GET" so people could understand better that its a GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confuse partial and incomplete requests:

- partial: request for some part of a resource, that is a Range request like shown in the answer of falsetru. This will not cause a timeout but instead a response with code 206 and your requested part of the resource.
- incomplete: your request is incomplete and cannot be processed by the server, thus it will wait for the rest of the request and timeout after a while if it does not get the request. In your question you already have such an incomplete request because you did not finish you request properly (it must end with `\r\n\r\n` and not a single `\n`). Other ways are just a TCP connect without sending any data or doing a POST request with a content-length and then not sending as much data as specified in the request header.

Comment: So that means the get request I posted will be time outed after a time of about 400 seconds right?

Comment: How fast this will timeout will depend on the configuration of the server. Usually servers with high load will timeout incomplete requests fairly quickly to fight attempts of denial of service attacks.

Comment: How could I do this also in a POST request?

Comment: Similar to GET, just don't send the complete request. One way would be to set the content-length to 100 but provide only 50 bytes content or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP headers ends too early. (`\n\n` should come after headers, before the contents)

```
import socket, sys
host = sys.argv[1]

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+host+"\nUser-Agent:Mozilla 5.0\n\n"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, 80))
s.send(request)
response = s.recv(1024)
```

If you mean partial content retrieval, you can speicfy [`Range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35):

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+host+"\nUser-Agent:Mozilla 5.0\rRange: bytes=0-999\n\n"
```

**NOTE**

It should be `\r\n` not `\n` as line end, even if most (but not all) servers accept `\n` too.

Comment: It should be `\r\n` not `\n` as line end, even if most (but not all) servers accept `\n` too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, Thank you for comment. I added your comment in the answer. Is it okay?